# an increase in output of 15%/ an increase of a certain percentage

Tags: grammar

In my context, I am speaking of a production function and a percentage increase. The production function: **Y = F(K, L)**, where Y - output in units, K - tools in units - capital, L - hours spent on work.

z- a percentage increase, so **zY = F(zK, zL)**.

I've formulated two sentences which are supposed to convey the same meaning,

> zY = F(zK, zL).

Do the sentences below reflect the above idea correctly from the point of view of English grammar?

> An increase of the same percentage in all factor quantities will lead to an increase in output of the same percentage.

or

> An increase of 15% in all factor quantities will lead to an increase in output of 15%.

Comment: Yes, both of those are correct English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two places I think you can improve this:

1. There are only two factors, so it might be better to use *both* instead of *all*. Save *all* for when there are three or more factors.
2. I'm not sure you need to use the word "quantities" – and I think the sentences may read better without that word.

So, with my suggestions, the sentences would be:

> An increase of the same percentage in both factors will lead to an increase in output of the same percentage.
>
> An increase of 15% in both factors will lead to an increase in output of 15%.

Although I might say it this way:

> Increasing both factors by the same percentage will cause output to increase by that same percentage.

That's grammatical, but I'm not convinced your theoretical increase would be realized in practice, due to the law of diminishing returns. But that's not a matter of English.   :^)

Comment: This is one of properties of a production function, which is called constant returns to scale. When we change all inputs equally, output also changes at the same proportion. :-) I do not know exactly whether /where it can be realized in practice. As Wiki says, a firm has economies of scale if and only if it has increasing returns to scale, has diseconomies of scale if and only if it has decreasing returns to scale, and has neither economies nor diseconomies of scale if it has constant returns to scale. @J.R.

Comment: I wonder whether it is justified to put the value of increase after some words that follow the word 'increase', but not directly after 'increase'? [an increase in output of 15%]

Comment: @Humbulani - Nothing wrong with that, but another way to word it would be "a 15% increase in output".