# Usage of 'increase in' and 'increase of'

Tags: word-choice, difference, word-in-context

> People with A exhibited a significant increase *in* proteins A, B and C.
>
> XYZ is an event resulting in the decrease *in* protein C.
>
> A is increased in people with PQR. This **increase of (in) A** is particularly significant.

From [1](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/206256/prepositions-increase-of-vs-increase-in), [2](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/increase-of-or-increase-in.828163/), [3](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/350931/increase-of-versus-increase-in) and numerous other pages on this topic I was led to understand that sentences 1 and 2 would use the preposition '*in*' instead of '*of*'. But in sentence 3, since the stress is more on the 'increase' and not the 'amount', would we use of or in?

When I read 'increase of A' as a single 'entity' it sounds right. But since the word 'amount' or 'level' is implied, 'in' also sounds like it fits. In fact, the more I think about it, the more confused I get. Can someone please help?

Comment: Try searching for **prepositions with the word increase** and do a research. Did you try doing a search here on ELL?

Comment: I did. The links I have given are actually the first three pages in the search results. Like these pages, most ELL questions have [distinct numbers] (https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/41570/an-increase-in-output-of-15-an-increase-of-a-certain-percentage) (in which case 'in' would work) or are about [general differences] (https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/98343/a-comparison-between-in-and-of) between the prepositions. I wanted to know about their use in this particular context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best I can tell you is that **in** is correct while **of** seams to be wrong.

Cambridge explains the use of **"increase of"** as a noun here: [**Nouns and prepositions** from English Grammar Today](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/about-nouns/nouns-and-prepositions)

> - *There has been an increase of 200,000 in the city’s population in the last ten years.*
>     (**Of** is used before numbers and quantities after *increase/decrease/growth*; **in** is used before the thing affected by the change.)
>     **Not**: *… an increase of the city’s population …*

**"[an increase in](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/increase)"** indicates growth of something that gets bigger in number or volume. [(Longman Dictionary)](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/increase)

Based on what is known I can assume that a possible correct structure of the 3rd sentence using **of** can be the following:

- A is increased in people with PQR. This *increase in people of A * is particularly significant.

You could restructure it and drop the **of (in) A** part to stay clear of unnecessary problems:

- A is increased in people with PQR. This increase is particularly significant.

Answer (score 3):

> A is increased in people with PQR.  This increase *in/of* A is particularly significant.

You use the preposition "**in**" after the noun "**increase**" when you talk about what increases.  As for the preposition "**of**" after this noun, you use it with a number or percentage; the amount by which something is increased. For examples:

- This *increase in production* is significant.
- This *increase of 30% in production* is significant.
- An *increase in the crime rate*.
- An *increase of 20% in the crime rate*.
- An *increase of 20 cents in the tax on fuel*.

In the sentence presented by the OP, we are not referring to the amount in number or percentage by which A is increased, so we cannot use the preposition "**of**" after the word "**increase**".  Instead, we should use the preposition "**in**".